# Render all video in folder with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, metadata

- I have a folder containing a lot of 2-10 min videos ....(30 video in folder)
- How to process multiple videos in a folder and cut videos into small videos 55s.

1. This is the line of code to process the entire folder containing videos

> @ECHO OFF
> Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
> set INPUT=C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\in
> set OUTPUT=C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\out
> : encode video
> for %%a in ("%INPUT%*.mp4") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -r 30 -b:v 1000k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -preset superfast "%OUTPUT%/%%~na.mp4"

2. This is the code to cut 55s video

> ffmpeg -i 11.mp4 -filter_complex "crop=ih*(9/16):ih" -crf 21 -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 55 -reset_timestamps 1 -preset ultrafast chep49_%03d.mp4

3. Error command to process multiple Video Files using batch file

[image]
====>>> The question is how to combine the above 2 sentences into 1
====>>> Can you help me please?

Comment: Relating to the output names would that be correct: If the original filename is Chep.mp4. The 55 second movies should be Chep_001.mp4, Chep_002.mp4, Chep_003.mp4, Chep_004.mp4 and so on and do this for a whole folder of movies?

Comment: you're right, that's obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if it is this that you want:

[image]

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set INPUT=C:\users\ABC\Desktop\in
set OUTPUT=C:\users\ABC\desktop\out

:: encode video:

for %%a in ("%INPUT%\*.*") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -r 30 -b:v 1000k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -preset superfast -filter_complex "crop=ih*(9/16):ih" -crf 21 -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 55 -reset_timestamps 1 -preset ultrafast "%output%\%%~na_%%03d.mp4"
```

Update 12/04/2022:

```
@ECHO OFF
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set INPUT=%userprofile%\Desktop\in
set OUTPUT=%userprofile%\desktop\out

:: encode video:

for %%a in ("%INPUT%\*.*") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 60 -r 30 -b:v 1000k -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -preset superfast -filter_complex "crop=ih*(9/16):ih,drawtext=text='Centered Text':font=Arial:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white" -crf 21 -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 12 -reset_timestamps 1 -preset ultrafast "%output%\%%~na_%%03d.mp4"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the command line works perfectly

Comment: I have added this code to process more commands but it still fails, can you help me to complete it?
"drawtext=text='Centered Text':fontfile=c\:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white, crop=ih*(9/16):ih" -crf 21 -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 12 -reset_timestamps 1 -preset ultrafast "%output%\%%~na_%%03d.mp4"

Comment: Look at the update part in my answer, for me I got something like this on one of the 12 sec segments: https://i.imgur.com/MEiA2le.png is that the intention?

Comment: I used your code update and got this error on my machine ... Is my device faulty?

https://imgur.com/pVkdGeH
https://imgur.com/a/sUu6CbO

Comment: For me it worked just by putting the font name font=Arial, maybe try: fontfile=c\:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf or check if that font is actually installed in your system.

Comment: Or try another font like 'Times New' courier new, calibri, georgia

Comment: I think I have all those fonts on my computer
https://i.imgur.com/dNUiXlh.jpg

Comment: I switched to another computer with the same error

Comment: I have added the command to insert logo instead of inserting text, thank you for your enthusiastic support. wish you good health

Comment: maybe you just need a newer ffmpeg version.....

Comment: Oh, that's right. i changed to the latest ffmpeg and it's fun. your code worked perfectly